# Entering a group of numbers sequentially in specific positions in a matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to enter a group of numbers in this matrix sequentially. Here is an example:
Suppose that:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]  % Group of numbers
A =                      % The matrix
1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3
3.1 4.2 1.1 7.4 5.6 2.2 1.3
1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3
1.6 3.2 6.3 2.1 2.6 7.2 1.3
6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3
2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3
```

What I am trying to do is to find a way using loops to enter the group of numbers stored in x to be in the following way:

```
A =                      % The matrix
1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 3.1 4.2 1.1 7.4 5.6 2.2 1.3 3.1 4.2 1.1 7.4 5.6 2.2 1.3
1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3
1.6 3.2 6.3 2.1 2.6 7.2 1.3 1.6 3.2 6.3 2.1 2.6 7.2 1.3 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3 6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3 6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3
2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3 2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3 2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3
```

As you can notice the group of numbers (from 1.0 to 7.0) moves down (row by row) till the end of the matrix. At each move the matrix dimension increases as well. I believe that I should define the matrix dimension first.
To do so, I found that multiplying the matrix columns by the number of rows
I will get the new matrix dimension which in this case will be 7 (rows) x 49 (columns).

I need to know how to create such a matrix automatically using for loop or any other possible way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use repmat in order to concat 3 copies of your matrix horizontally.
2. Use the Matlab's assignment syntax: A(row,col:col+length(x)-1) in order to copy x into the desired row and col.

Code example:

```
outA = repmat(A,1,3); %replicate A
outA(2,1:length(x)) = x; %inserts x into the beginning of the 2nd row
outA(4,size(outA,2)-length(x)+1:end) = x; %inserts x into the end of the 4th row
```

Results:

```
outA = 
1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.1 5.3 1.2 1.3
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 3.1 4.2 1.1 7.4 5.6 2.2 1.3 3.1 4.2 1.1 7.4 5.6 2.2 1.3
1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3 1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3 1.4 5.2 4.3 2.2 4.3 3.2 1.3
1.6 3.2 6.3 2.1 2.6 7.2 1.3 1.6 3.2 6.3 2.1 2.6 7.2 1.3 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3 6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3 6.1 1.3 9.4 4.2 3.3 1.2 1.3
2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3 2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3 2.5 4.2 3.2 5.1 6.7 1.2 1.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That gives me a very nice start to do it.
Hope you a nice day

Comment: Happy to help! If it solved your question 100%, please accept the answer by marking the V sign from the left. If you have any more questions of clarifications don't hesitate to ask